# Why doesn't sed -i work with /proc/PID/fd/FD

Tags: linux, shell, sed, io-redirection, file-descriptors

I have this file and fd: `exec 88<>abc`

Why

```
$ sed -i "s/cd/II/g" /proc/$$/fd/88
sed: couldn't open temporary file /proc/26194/fd/sedS1D1FT: No such file or directory
```

but this work:

```
$ cat /proc/self/fd/88 | sed  "s/cd/II/g" 
abIIefg
```

And then this doesn't work:

```
$ (cat /proc/self/fd/88 | sed  "s/cd/II/g")  > /proc/self/fd/88
```

this causes `/proc/self/fd/88` to become empty

Comment: What are you expecting would happen when you do in-place editing (`-i`) on a file descriptor?

Comment: file under `/proc` are not files, but rather pseudo file or view of actual process or files. I suspect this editing come from an **XY-Problem** :


https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 6):

`sed -i` does not actually edit the file "in-place", ever; it works by redirecting its output to a temporary file, then renaming/moving the temporary file to the original.

That makes sure that the original file is not lost in case something goes wrong mid-way.

To make things worse, `sed` (just like `vim`) tries to create the temporary file in the same directory as the original.

The `/proc` filesystem is *synthetic*, you cannot just create or move files inside it; that's why you're getting that error. But even if `sed` was creating the temporary file in `/tmp`, the last operation (the renaming of the temporary file to the original) would still fail.

You can try to do what `sed -i` does in a round-about manner:

```
$ ised(){ for a; do :; done; t=`mktemp` && sed "$@" > "$t" && cat "$t" > "$a" && rm "$t"; }
$ ised s/cd/II/g /proc/$$/fd/88
```

The filename should always be the last argument to `ised`.

This breaks the consistency guarantee of `sed -i`; the `cat in > out` operation, unlike `rename("in", "out")`, is not atomic; if stopped in the middle, the `out` file will be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the actual file still exists, this might work better, (but use with caution since it would modify an actual file):

```
sed -i s/cd/II/g "$(realpath "/proc/$$/fd/88")"
```

---

[As *mosvy* notes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480307/why-sed-i-doesnt-work-with-fd/480493?noredirect=1#comment879301_480493), this will not work if the result of `realpath /proc/$$/fd/88` was already deleted. Example:

```
exec 7>/tmp/junk; echo yes >&7; rm /tmp/junk; 
cat /proc/$$/fd/7; cat "$(realpath "/proc/$$/fd/7")"
```

Output (even though */tmp/junk* doesn't exist), 1st line to *STDOUT*, 2nd line to *STDERR*:

```
yes
cat: '/tmp/junk (deleted)': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Using `sed -i` implies that you want to modify an actual file, what do you mean with that word of caution?

Comment: This will not work if the "realpath" of `/proc/$$/fd/88` was already deleted. Example: `exec 7>/tmp/junk; echo yes >&7; rm /tmp/junk; cat /proc/$$/fd/7; cat "$(realpath "/proc/$$/fd/7")"`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, the *OP*'s understanding of  `/proc/$$/fd` was inaccurate, and might benefit from reinforcement.